# Question about the energy levels of Rubidium atom - how to understand this energy level diagram?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, cold-atoms

But today when I try to read some papers working with Alkaline atom, I couldn't figure out how they plot the Rubidium energy level. From my undergraduate study, I thought the diagram of Rubidium atom should be something like this, the outer layer electron is on the energy level of $5S$:

[image]

The spin up and spin down electrons occupied the energy levels from ground state go upward. But I cannot figure out how to read the diagrams of ${ }^{87} \mathbf{R b}$ below:

[image]

So my questions are:

- How could the 5P energy levels be occupied?
- What does the subscript $S_{1/2}$ and $P_{3/2}$ means? Does this means spin? But electron should only have spin number $\pm 1$, right?
- What is the F quantum number? It is not the F from the "spdf" orbital notation, right?
- Can anyone draw a diagram of ${ }^{87} \mathbf{R b}$ with all **energy levels** and the **relationship between different quantum numbers**?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [Russel-Saunders term symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol).

Comment: another point: electrons have spin + or - 1/2.

Comment: @user10001111 sorry, my fault.

Comment: @ZizhengYang: if my answer answers your question, please upvote and accept the answer

Comment: You have the option of changing the answer you accept, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubidium is an alkali metal which is frequently used in atomic physics. The diagram refers ONLY to the outer electron. This outer electron is the interesting thing in atomic physics and Rubidium is called "hydrogen-like".
Concerning your questions:

> - How could the 5P energy levels be occupied?

Via excitation with a laser. This is indicated by the 780.2 nm.

> What does the subscript S1/2
> and P3/2 means? Does this means spin? But electron should only have spin number ±1
> , right?

It's not only the spin of the electron, but also the orbital angular momentum. These spins add in a very specific way.

> What is the F quantum number? It is not the F from the "spdf" orbital notation, right?

No. F denotes the total angular momentum taking into account the spin of the electron, the angular orbital momentum and the spin of the atoms core.

> Can anyone draw a diagram of 87Rb
> with all energy levels and the relationship between different quantum numbers?

Mate... this is a whole atomic physics lecture. It's not that easy. Look for the Schrödinger Equation of an Hydrogen Atom. I personally like the book of C.Foot - Atomic physics.
https://books.google.de/books?id=yf6BAwAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

They are talking about atomic term symbols. And beaware that we are looking at a many-electron atom. They look like: $^{2S+1}L_J$ where S denotes the total spin, L denotes the total orbital angular momentum. J denotes the total angular momentum (which is between |L-S| and L+S). Look a bit into basic quantum mechanics

Comment: The F's come from nuclear spin.

Comment: Why are people down voting this answer? And I cannot remove this answer, because it already has been accepted...